# Google Sheets Script - More concise code to run on specific sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I only want the script to run on sheets 'Trip 1' to 'Trip 3'.

This is the script I'm using:

```js
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A4:K";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 2, ascending: false},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 6, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
{column: 7, ascending: true},
{column: 8, ascending: true},
];

function onEdit(event){
   var editedRange= event.range;
   var editedSheet= editedRange.getSheet()

  if(editedRange.getColumn() == 2 && editedSheet.getName() == "Trip 1")
  { 
   var range = editedSheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
    range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }

  else if(editedRange.getColumn() == 2 && editedSheet.getName() == "Trip 2")
  { 
    var range = editedSheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
    range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }

  else if(editedRange.getColumn() == 2 && editedSheet.getName() == "Trip 3")
  {  
    var range = editedSheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
    range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a constant - an array with the names of the sheets on which you want to apply sorting `SORT_ON_SHEETS = ['Trip 1','Trip 2','Trip 3']`

And in the onEdit() function, check if this [array includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp) the name of the sheet where the event occurred

```
function onEdit(event){
   var editedRange= event.range;
   var editedSheet= editedRange.getSheet()

  if (editedRange.getColumn() == 2 && SORT_ON_SHEETS.includes(editedSheet.getName())){
    var range = editedSheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
    range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function onEdit(event){
   var editedRange= event.range;
   var editedSheet= editedRange.getSheet()    
   if(editedRange.getColumn() == 2 && (editedSheet.getName() == "Trip 1" || "Trip 2" || "Trip 3")){ 
   var range = editedSheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
   range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }    
}
```